# mongo db create accurate index

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database

I want to create a mongodb index for the following query:

```
{
  "$and": [
    {
      "$or": [
        {
          "connector_name": {
            "$options": "i",
            "$regex": "plop"
          }
        },
        {
          "connector": {
            "$options": "i",
            "$regex": "plop"
          }
        },
        {
          "component": {
            "$options": "i",
            "$regex": "plop"
          }
        },
        {
          "resource": {
            "$options": "i",
            "$regex": "plop"
          }
        },
        {
          "domain": {
            "$options": "i",
            "$regex": "plop"
          }
        },
        {
          "perimeter": {
            "$options": "i",
            "$regex": "plop"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "$or": [
        {
          "event_type": {
            "$eq": "check"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried the following indexes creation unsuccessfully:

**first indexes try:**

```
db.events.ensureIndex({'event_type': 1});
db.events.ensureIndex({'connector_name': 1});
db.events.ensureIndex({'connector': 1});
db.events.ensureIndex({'component': 1});
db.events.ensureIndex({'resource': 1});
db.events.ensureIndex({'domain': 1});
db.events.ensureIndex({'perimeter': 1});
```

**second indexes try:**

```
db.events.ensureIndex({'event_type': 1, 'connector_name': 1});
db.events.ensureIndex({'event_type': 1, 'connector': 1});
db.events.ensureIndex({'event_type': 1, 'component': 1});
db.events.ensureIndex({'event_type': 1, 'resource': 1});
db.events.ensureIndex({'event_type': 1, 'domain': 1});
db.events.ensureIndex({'event_type': 1, 'perimeter': 1});
```

**third indexes try:**

```
db.events.ensureIndex(
{
    'event_type': 1,
    'connector_name': 1,
    'connector': 1,
    'component': 1,
    'resource': 1,
    'domain': 1,
    'perimeter': 1,
})
```

Each time and following [mongo explain query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) , I looked at the "indexOnly" and "nscanned" fields that means (as i understood) the good mongo use of my indexes. However, until now, results are poor and my query still does not use indexes. With all my tries, I still don't understand where I am wrong with mongodb indexing system.

Comment: You are using case-insensitive regex matches which will always result in a full index scan (at best) .. and with `$or` clauses the `nscanned` values are going to add up to the cardinality of all the fields you are comparing. Can you describe what you actually need to search for - just keywords or do you need to do substring matches across all these fields?

Comment: With this query, I want to find all matching document that contains the queryed value here it is "plop" . For now, i will try to do a case sensitive search as you suggested hoping that mongo will use my indexes. In fact , this query's purpose is to perform a search in my document as well as a search engine. That s why my search is that permissive.

Comment: I changed my query and now it looks like          
    "$or": [
            {
              "connector_name": {
                "$regex": "/^Sphinx.*/"
              }
            },...

with the third index model I described before but indexed search still does not work properly

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({connectorname:"text",connector:"text",component:"text"...})
```

Which creates a text index over the fields. Then, you can query like

```
db.collection.find({$or:[{$text:{$search:"plop"},{event_type:"check"}]})
```

which will return all documents which contain the search term in the fields the text index was created for or which have event_type == "check".

See [the MongoDB docs on "Text Indices"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/) for details.

Comment: Hallo Markus, the text field cannot work in my case as told in mongo documentation : [text indices](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/) **A collection can have at most one text index.** However, I would need many of these search fields in my case

Comment: I know the documentation well enough. Why would you need more than one text index? Simply create a compound index as shown. You could use an aggregation instead of a query to exclude documents which contain the search term in unwanted fields.